# Update Office add-in manifest after deploying

Tags: office365

How do i make sure that users of an Office add-in that I deploy through the Office store get an updated manifest when I upload a new one to the store. In particular in the case that the user has the add-in opened with their saved document? (and thus a user who gets the document forwarded with the add-in opened as well). I might want to edit the URL in the manifest to a different location after deploying and that will break the add-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to worry about that. Even when a user receives a document with an add-in already open in it, the host (e.g. Word) will still check the store periodically for a new manifest. If you've changed the add-in's URL the add-in will fail to load first, but you should get a prompt a little later (after the store check is done) that asks you to reload the latest version of the add-in (which actually means manifest in this case).

Comment: To add to that a bit:  the add-in will generally be updated the very next time that it's launched (either inserted or activated via a document open).  That being said, it's a good practice to do a URL redirect just in case, and/or keep your existing code running for a bit (so that users who currently already have your add-in open and navigate from one page to another don't get a page-not-found error.